# Issues with gradle build in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

This is the situation:

I deleted app.impl and build.properties in my project. I used to do this all the time, but now when I rebuild gradle project, only app.impl is created, build.properties is missing.

When I navigate in application, in certain scenarios I get the following error:

```
07-04 10:38:37.784 14201-14201/net.-.- E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: net.-.-, PID: 14201
                                                                    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field scrollView of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id' appears in /data/app/net.dycode.eorder2-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupContent(AlertController.java:675)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:463)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:215)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:257)
                                                                        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:395)
                                                                        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:294)
                                                                        at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:502)
                                                                        at net.dycode.eorder2.dialog.AlertDialogFragment.onStart(AlertDialogFragment.java:48)
```

What I have tried:

- checking out different branch (granted it worked correctly before)
- cleaning project
- rebuilding project
- making project
- making app

I also tried updating android studio and it's SDK. Now there are no available updates.

Comment: have you been able to fix this issue? i am experiencing the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem only by uninstalling android studio, deleting everything that is even remotely associated with it and then installing android studio again.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
->clean project
->delete build folder
->rebuilding project
```

or try this command from terminal

```
gradlew clean
```

Comment: Tried gradlew clean - did not help

Comment: You try delete whole build folder and then rebuild?

Comment: Yes, I have tried deleting the entire build folder and then running gradlew clean. Project builds without any issues, but application works incorrectly (description above).